# Manually edit spelling entries in RStudio dictionary

Tags: rstudio

While editing an R Markdown file, I accidentally added the word 'teh' to the current dictionary when performing a spell check. Is there a way to manually edit the dictionary to undo this incorrect entry?

I am running RStudio version 1.1.423 on macOS Sierra (10.12.6).

Answer (score 2):

I found the user dictionary. On macOS, you can edit the text file `~/.rstudio-desktop/monitored/lists/user_dictionary`.

Comment: BTW: I found the answer on the RStudio support page: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200655116-Delete-words-added-to-dictionary

Answer (score 2):

The link where the OP found the solution appears to have been taken down, so for Windows users the location is: `%localappdata%\RStudio-Desktop\monitored\lists\user_dictionary`

Comment: On my machine it's in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\RStudio\monitored\lists\user_dictionary` (RStudio 2022.07.1+554).

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, it is located at this path `%localappdata%\RStudio\monitored\lists\user_dictionary`